# Best way to use Orbeon as a REST service

Tags: orbeon, xforms, exist-db

I have a set of XForms already running within eXist-db that are automatically generated by an XQuery.  Is there any way form me to call a REST service, supplied by Orbeon, running on a separate tomcat server,  that will convert the XForms files into HTML that I can display in a web browser?

In other words I would like to do something like:

```
xquery version "1.0";
...
let $my-xforms-file := local:my-generate-xforms($spec-file)
let $orbeon-rendered-xforms := httpclient:post('http://localhost/tomcat/orbeon/getpost',  $my-xforms-file)
return $html-file
```

What I want is really just a render conversion service for XForms that gets an HTTP POST with the XForms in the document body and it returns something that I can render with a web browser.

Is there a component to do this already built into Orbeon?  I am glad to document this, provide an XQuery module to support it and share with others.

Answer (score 4):

There is a REST service for using the Orbeon forms runner, but it uses HTTP GET, not HTTP POST.

The service is offered as part of the forms runner "Sandbox" Here is a sample:

If you have Tomcat running on port 8081 (not the default) and eXist running on port 8080 then the following will work:

```
http://localhost:8081/orbeon/xforms-sandbox/run?url=http://localhost:8080/exist/apps/grants/orbeon-tests/01-min.xml
```

The sandbox also has a way to get the data from a file system

You can't get to form runner standbox from the menus.  To get there you have to manually put the following URL into your browser:

```
http://localhost:8081/orbeon/xforms-sandbox/
```

Comment: Indeed, I think this is better way to do it. I.e., instead of the browser hitting your app (your own XQuery in eXist) and your app pushing the XForms to Orbeon for processing, the browser hits Orbeon which pulls the form from your app (eXist in this case). Using the XForms sandbox is quick way to make it work, but you could also develop your own custom logic with XPL and the page flow within Orbeon that does something similar.

Comment: You could also just get inspiration from the Sandbox app and create your own with POST support.